# Get image width after change visibility from gone

Tags: android

I has constraint layout with `ImageView` inside it:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_lottery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_lottery_info"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
```

In my fragment, when I recieve network response, I show `ImageView` and try load image from network via `Picasso` and resize it with autoheight.

```
mIvLottery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Picasso.get().load(mLottery.getBanner()).resize(mIvLottery.getWidth(), 0).into(mIvLottery);
```

The problem is: `mIvLottery.getWidth()` is 0.

How I can solve it?

If I change in xml layout `android:visibility from` `gone` to `invisible` or `visible`, all works fine. The problem is only when default visibility of `ImageView` is `gone`.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/2164363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `mIvLottery` visibility is set to `GONE` is perfectly fine that the width is 0.

You have several solutions here, but not knowing what your constraints are I'd say the quickest would be extracting the width from `mLottery.getBanner()`.

Otherwise, if you need to calculate the width of a view not yet displayed on the screen you can rely on the [`measure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#measure(int,%20int)) API.

So calling `measure()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` afterward should give you the width you are looking for. Bear in mind that measure accepts [View.MeasureSpec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec) as parameters, so it depends on the parent layout which ones to choose

```
mIvLottery.measure(UNSPECIFIED, AT_MOST);
int width = mIvLottery.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: I call `mIvLottery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` before call `getWidth();`. Width of item not calculated immediately after set item `visibility` to `View.VISIBLE`? Why?

Comment: Does the solution work? Changing the visibility of the view does not imply an immediate layout pass. But there are other APIs to force layout invalidation.

Comment: By the way, to force a view to be laid out, so it can be measured you can call `mIvLottery.forceLayout();`

Comment: `measure` takes [`MeasureSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec) as parameters. `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` is invalid in this context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @EugenPechanec, I always erroneously used layout params, and never had a problem. I'll be happy to edit my current answer, which are going to be the correct measures? UNSPECIFIED, AT_MOST?

Comment: The parent view is responsible for measuring and layout. We should ask "what would the parent layout put here". Right now only @igor_rp can guess.